# Knitr and tangle code without execution

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to convert a pretty critical database interface script to R markdown for documentation purposes, with the intent of then tangling that file to produce the R code that goes into my crontab. I've found however that if I set `eval=T` then kniting the file runs the code (which I don't want to happen unexpectedly) and if I set `eval=F` then tangling the file produces all commented code.

Is there a safe way to produce a file that tangles into runnable code without running the risk of execution? I suppose I could find/replace `eval=F` every time but that seems inelegant.

Comment: If you want the just the code, not run, why not just put it in a normal markdown codeblock instead of in a Knitr chunk (\`\`\`r your code \`\`\`)? No risk of running at all

Comment: I'd like the option to `tangle` it back out into a pure R file. I'm trying to create documentation in one file with the code, in hopes that it's more likely to stay updated that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by writing a chunk hook function. See the source code of `knitr::hook_purl` for an example. Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(purl = function(before, options) {
  if (before) return()
  input  = current_input()  # filename of input document
  output = paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(input), 'R', sep = '.')
  if (knitr:::isFALSE(knitr:::.knitEnv$tangle.start)) {
    assign('tangle.start', TRUE, knitr:::.knitEnv)
    unlink(output)
  }
  cat(options$code, file = output, sep = '\n', append = TRUE)
})
```

If you set up this chunk hook in your document, all code chunks will be written out, regardless of the chunk option `eval = TRUE` or `FALSE`. Note you have to put this in the first code chunk in your document.

If your input document has a simple structure (e.g. no cross-chunk references), there is an even easier approach: you can obtain all code chunks via `knitr:::knit_code$get()`, and all you need to do is to write all of them to an R script.

Comment: Is there a way to use this mechanism to uncomment the lines in the process? I can gsub the comments out otherwise.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy It seems you did not try it -- it does not comment out any lines at all.

Comment: I did, that was what kept me from responding for a few days. A minimal example:

http://pastebin.com/zX3EfSCC

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy Use the default tangle=FALSE instead of TRUE. Knitting and tangling can be done at the same time.

Comment: If I flip that flag and run `knit('/tmp/atest.Rmd',tangle=F,output="/tmp/atest.R")` then I just get the markdown in the output .R file. 

For what it's worth, adding a function with `knitr:::knit_code$get()`,`gsub()` to remove commenting and `writeLines()` at the bottom does allow me to produce the desired output.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy `setwd('/tmp/'); knit('atest.Rmd')` and you get `atest.R`; the documentation `?knit` has warned about using an `output` path that contains a directory (in most cases, you should not set `output` at all, unless you really really understand what it means to set it)

Comment: When I do this, it does produce atest.R, however it's an empty file.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy Fair enough. I just tested it and updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Revisiting this question *years* later, there is a much easier answer:

You can combine the code chunk arguments `eval=FALSE, comment=NA` to:

1. Avoid running the code chunk when running `knit()`, and
2. Print code without comments when running `purl()`

This argument is described on the page: https://yihui.org/knitr/options/ in a section called "Code Decoration".

Perhaps this is already described in another post somewhere, but I just spent *hours* trying to figure out how to do this with "hooks" and `knitr` source code before finding the answer that I knew must be out there. Hope this makes it easier for the next person!